# CHARINDEX Function is not supported by Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

```
col1=LEFT([col2], CHARINDEX('_', [col2]) - 1)
```

I am trying to join on columns and I should match col1 data equal to col2 data, but in col2 it should check the characters before the delimiter value '_'

What can I use in the join condition instead on Charindex in Tableau, as this is not supported by Tableau.

```
col1

abc
dcb

col2 
abc_123
dcb_123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a calculated field to use in your joins. The split() function is available and is designed for exactly this purpose. That is you can use split() to obtain the substring before the underscore, which you can use a join key